# Dynamic category name in query post

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, archives

I want to make the following query_posts to use the current page's category name. For example, the user is located at: examplesite.com/category/apples/, and i want to use "apples" and for a different category (say "pears"), then dynamically add "pears to the following query_posts function:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=apples'); ?>
```

Also, can this be amended to display only posts from a custom post type called, say "fruits"? How would this look like?

Comment: I'm new to php and wordpress.
I am building an archive template that has to make a masonry gallery with all the posts of the current category.
I have to replace the 'edito' with a dynamic piece of code that give me the actual category name. Can you help me to figure out how to do it? Thanks ! <?php $args = array( 'category_name' => 'edito', 'post_type' => 'post', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'DESC', ); $child_query = new WP_Query( $args ); $first = true; $same_date = 'dd'; while ( $child_query->have_posts() ) : $child_query->the_post(); $divclass = ''; $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_i

Comment: @sandro this isn't a discussion forum, do not post replies or new questions as the solution. Ask a new question instead or leave a comment. I converted what you posted into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `query_posts` functions. You should create instance of `WP_Query` class

In your theme folder create a new file called `category-slug.php`. You can copy the `category.php` file or `archive.php` file to create `category-slug.php` file.

Then in the new `category-slug.php` file before the `while` loop you can write your query.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=apple,pears' );

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You might need to replace your existing while statement with this one.

Comment: thanks karun, this does work perfectly, but is there anyway to use this without separate category-slug php files?

is there any way for the WP_Query to get the loaded page's category name? Maybe using get_the_category?

Comment: you can try adding `if..else` condition before the `while` loop in your `category.php` file. Like if this is a specific category term then use this query else just as it is.